# How to move View in HStack to the top of the other views

Tags: swiftui

I have a set of subviews that are arranged within an HStack. I have a transition that is run whenever a view is selected successfully, but it is occluded by neighbouring views "above" it.

I found this article here, but I can't see how to integrate it into my solution:
[How to bring a view on top of VStack containing ZStacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62812260/how-to-bring-a-view-on-top-of-vstack-containing-zstacks)

[image: The view transitioning from the view moves up in front of some hexagons, and behind others]

Is there a way of getting the selected view to pop on top of the others?

```
HStack(spacing: -75)
{
    ForEach(viewModel.hexagons){hexagon in
        let hexagonFrame = getFrameFor(hexagon: hexagon, minWidth: smallSide)
        let colorArray = getColorsFor(hexagon: hexagon)
        ZStack()
        {
            let thisIndex = hexagon.id
            HexagonView(strokeColor: colorArray[0]).onTapGesture(perform: {
                viewModel.chooseHexagon(hexagon: hexagon)
            })
            .scaleEffect(hexagon.pressed ? 1.2 : 1.0)
            .animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 0.2))
            if hexagon.isSelected
            {
                Circle().fill(playerColorArray[hexagon.playerIndex]).frame(width: hexagonFrame.width * fontScalingFactor, height: hexagonFrame.height * fontScalingFactor, alignment: .center)
                Circle().stroke(Color.black).frame(width: hexagonFrame.width * fontScalingFactor, height: hexagonFrame.height * fontScalingFactor, alignment: .center)
            }
            else
            {
                Text(verbatim: String(thisIndex+1)).font(Font.system(size: hexagonFrame.size.width * fontScalingFactor)).foregroundColor(colorArray[1])
                .onTapGesture(perform: {
                        viewModel.chooseHexagon(hexagon: hexagon)
                })
                .scaleEffect(hexagon.pressed ? 1.2 : 1.0)
                .animation(Animation.easeIn(duration: 0.5))
            }
```

This is the view that animates up from the haxagon that has been selected

```
        if hexagon.isSelected && hexagon.pressed
        {
            Text(String(viewModel.currentScore))
                .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                .font(Font.system(size: hexagonFrame.size.width * fontScalingFactor)).foregroundColor(colorArray[1])
                .transition(AnyTransition.asymmetric(insertion: .identity, removal: AnyTransition.move(edge: .top)))
                .animation(.easeIn(duration: 2.0))
                .zIndex(.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        }
    }
    .position(x: hexagonFrame.origin.x + hexagonFrame.size.width / 3 - (scrollViewGeometry.size.width/2), y: (scrollViewGeometry.size.height/2) - hexagonFrame.origin.y)
    .frame(width: hexagonFrame.size.width, height: hexagonFrame.size.height, alignment:.center)
    }
}.frame(width: (max(75, smallSide) * 8), height: (max(75, smallSide) * 5))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/61847909/12299030?

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!